# Are methods declared in servlets are thread-safe or the local variables in servlets are thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have got to know that there is race around condition in  my servlets as I have some globally declared variables which are used in it . So my question is if I declare those variables in some method apart from `doGet` or `doPost` method. Will they be not shared among different threads ?

If yes , how we can avoid race around condition . I want to avoid the use of `ThreadLocal` and usage of `singelThreadModel` .

Here is the example

```
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {


    private String userString1 = "";
    private String userString2 = "";


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        someTask(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        someTask(request, response);
    }

    public void someTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        userString1 = request.getParameter("someParameter");
        userString2 = request.getParameter("someParameter");

        }
}
```

NOTE : This is just an example , not the actual code .

Answer (score 0):

> Are methods declared in servlets are thread-safe

No.

> or the local variables in servlets are thread safe

No.

> I have got to know that there is race around condition in my servlets

There is a *race* condition.

> as I have some globally declared variables which are used in it.

You have some *instance* variables.

> So my question is if I declare those variables in some method apart from `doGet()` or `doPost()` method, will they be not shared among different threads?

Local variables are local to the method they are declared in.

> If yes, how we can avoid race around condition.

I can't follow your double negative, but it's still a *race* condition. Don't misuse standard terminology. You need to avoid instance members of a `Servlet` unless they are common to and shared by all possible concurrent invocations of its methods. Per-request variables must be method-local and passed around between methods as parameters or return values.

> I want to avoid the use of `ThreadLocal` and usage of `SingleThreadModel`.

You certainly do. There are no specified thread semantics in a `Servlet` that would make `ThreadLocal` work, and `SingleThreadModel` is deprecated and will be removed.

Comment: What if I declare  `private String userString1 = "";
    private String userString2 = "";
` in someTask method .

Will it solve the problem of race around condition ?

Comment: yes, that will solve it & you can't use `private` for a variable declared in a method ,  `String userString1 = request.getParameter("someParameter");`

Comment: @SabirKhan Thank You for your response . Is there some kind of documentation to which I can refer that these local variables are thread - safe . 

Also , I came to know from someone that there will be one one instance of public method which will let mulitple threads to share the information contained in local declared variables . Is that true ?

Comment: @SabirKhan No, declaring a `private String` member will *not* solve anything mentioned in this question.

Comment: @SidhantBansal Method-local variables are thread-safe *by definition*, unless they escape to another thread.

Comment: @EJP I am trying to something like Krishna is trying to do .

Comment: @SidhantBansal 'Only one instance of public method which will let multiple threads to share the information contained in local declared variables' is false. Either you have the same question, in which case the answer is also the same, or you have a new question, in which case you should ask it as such.

Comment: @EJP : just to clarify, I didn't say to change to a `private String` ...he already has that way. I said to make those variables as method local but he can't use `private` keyword for method local, I clarified that. .

Comment: @SidhantBansal : You need to familiarize yourself with basics of Java multi threading first then I would say reading a good book like - **Java Concurrency
In Practice**

Answer (score 0):

A Servlet is a Java class so its already thread - safe if it has no state ( i.e. if it doesn't have any state variables ) . No extra action is needed from your side.

Now , you introduce state variables like - `userString1` & `userString2` and your servlet can still be thread - safe since `String` is immutable but you are reassigning its reference for each request so it does not remain thread safe since assignments by one thread might change to some other value by some other thread ( by the time , thread one tries to use it ) . You can have an immutable as state & remain thread - safe , provided you don't reassign its reference the way you doing in `someTask` method.

So use those string variables provided its purpose is to pass some constant string to all request threads.

Also, in your code, you are putting lots of Strings on heap by that assignment expression in `someTask` method.

At last, you have to utilize java synchronization constructs to make your class thread safe if you have to use mutable state objects in those methods but again plain Java synchronization constructs are per JVM so you will face issues if deployment has to be distributed on a cluster. Some distributed locking mechanism will be needed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring a global variable and assigning the values in doGet or doPost method, they will definitely be overriden by different threads calling the servlet. You **should not** assign values to global variables in servlet method calls.

In your code what is stopping you from declaring the `userString1` & `userString2` inside method? Why do you want to declare them globally? If you want these variables to be used in different methods of the servlet, then simply pass them as method arguments instead of declaring them as global variables.

e.g.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userString1 = request.getParameter("someParameter");
    String userString2 = request.getParameter("someParameter");
    someTask(request, response, userString1, userString2);
}

public void someTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String userString1, String userString2) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //do whatever you want with these variables.
}
```

**OR**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    someTask(request, response);
}

public void someTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userString1 = request.getParameter("someParameter");
    String userString2 = request.getParameter("someParameter");

    //do whatever you want with these variables.
}
```

Comment: I was thinkig of declaring all these variables in `someTask` method . What is your point of view on this ?

Comment: Yeah you can declare these variables in `someTask` method as well. They will be thread safe as they are local to the method.

Comment: I am trying to do the same in my code . Will let you know once the things are don .

Comment: I have upvoted the answer but due to less reputation it will not be recorded .